# Hide Phone Number in status bar while Twilio call is in progress

Tags: android, react-native, twilio, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-programmable-voice

I have implemented twilio outbound call in react native using https://github.com/hoxfon/react-native-twilio-programmable-voice package. The outbound call is working fine. While in call in android the status bar shows users contact number. Is it possible to hide the number. Screenshot is attached below for reference.

[image]

Comment: change to setContentText(YOUR_CUSTOM_STRING) in CallNotificationManager

Comment: Can you please tell where to add and what to add exactly !!

Comment: it's a class in your repo link for android locate it CallNotificationManager and then search for setContentText there you will find it.

Comment: Can't we do anything without editing the package files, I don't think it is a good idea to edit the package file directly . Can we do it through app's android files?

Comment: For it you have to make your own notification by using callbacks from Twilio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a round about but not an ideal solution
Sending name in To and number in number.

```
await TwilioVoice.connect({ 
    To: this.props.route.params.buyerName, 
    Number: this.props.route.params.numberToCall
})
```

Comment: Looks like the [parameter `ToName`](https://github.com/hoxfon/react-native-twilio-programmable-voice/blob/1fd8f6fdb3148e82a67d282221675fec306cf28e/android/src/main/java/com/hoxfon/react/RNTwilioVoice/TwilioVoiceModule.java#L706-L708) might be better for you?

Comment: The notification manager automatically shows the field in To in the status bar, so the above one works perfectly for me. And the call dial connect process is handled from backend so the call is being placed from Number parameter.

Comment: Ok, just you described your solution as "no an ideal solution" so I was suggesting things that were maybe closer to ideal. If this is working and you are happy with it, go with it.